# Creating a truth table for two 4 bit numbers A[3:0] and B[3:0] for inputs and an output that is 1 when A and B are equal and 0 when false

Tags: digital-logic

I am having trouble creating this truth table. I know truth tables have every possible outcomes of A and B, such as A[3:0]

0000

0001

0010...

But when I place the inputs along together, A and B are always equal. This doesn't seem logical to me. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have 256 lines in your truth table.

- When B is 0000, A could be any of 0000 to 1111.
- When B is 0001, A could be any of 0000 to 1111.
- When B is 0010, A could be...

Well you get the point.

The output will only be 1 when A equals B which will be in 16 different cases.